# charCodeAt to C# conversion

Tags: c#, javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I want to convert this (ActionScript) function to C#, but can't figure out the charCodeAt

```
var _local_2 = "g";
var _local_3 = "h";
var _local_4:String = this.keycode((((((((("m" + _local_3) + "w") + _local_2) + "ffvn") + _local_2) + "63") + _local_3) + "d8"));

        private function keycode(_arg_1:String):String{
            var _local_2:* = "";
            var _local_3:int;
            while (_local_3 < _arg_1.length) {
                _local_2 = (_local_2 + String(_arg_1.substr(_local_3, 1)).charCodeAt(0));
                _local_3++;
            };
            return (_local_2);
        }
```

and output value of above keynote function on _local_4 is

```
109104119103102102118110103545110410056
```

But I don't know what should I use charCodAt in C# and get the ascii values.

Please help me convert it.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are just trying to return a substring with one character and then get char code (ascii value?) which you can get from using the index

```
 var _local_2 += _arg_1[_local_3];
```

---

Tested using the following function

```
    static int characterCount(string s)
    {
        int result = 0;
        foreach (var c in s)
            result += c;

        return result;
    }

//"test" == 448
```

Comment: yes I need to ascii value, but I don't know what is the alternative of charCodeAt in C#.. please help me

Comment: yes I tried, with above suggested code i am getting in input string back not the ascii values, Please look at the update question, I have also showed the output which I am getting in Flash Action Script3.

Comment: @ArbazAbid - I've added the function used to test this

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexer for getting the specific charcter from the string.

i think you want to get the first character from the substring, so you can use [0].

```
var _local_2 += _arg_1.Substring(_local_3, 1)[0].ToString();
```

Comment: I just update the question with full function, can you please take a look at it?